# Stack multiple push notifications with ionic and PushPlugin

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I've implemented in my hybrid mobile up push notifications on Android using Ionic Framework and [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git)

I need to send 3 notifications in the same timeframe for 3 most important articles. By sending in the payload notId I managed to send 3 notification without overwriting each other.

Now I'm trying to group them, similar to the attached image, the problem is that I can't find any information related to this, except some heavy Java. Maybe someone can point me how I could group my notifications that in expanded view would display all 3 of them under one tree ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: In huge capitals your link shows me: [DEPRECATED] Cordova Push Notifications Plugin for Android, iOS, WP8, Windows8, BlackBerry 10 and Amazon Fire OS

Comment: @Rienk It is, but does it matter ? The replacement is pretty much the same.

Comment: @Rienk I updated my app to use https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push 
I still can't find how to reach my goal.

Comment: @Rienk Thank you for the push to upgrade. The new plugin has stacking options https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push#inbox-stacking and solved my problem!

Comment: Nice to hear that lol

Comment: @CGeorges: How did you manage to make stacking work using Ionic? I've added `"android" => array("style" => "inbox", "summaryText" => "There are %n% notifications",...` but that didn't work.

Comment: @binoculars I couldn't, not with that plugin. I changed the plugin to https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push#inbox-stacking and I recommend you would too as that one is no longer maintained and misses a lot of features.

Comment: @CGeorges: I'm using the newer version of the plugin like you said, but stacking is not working either :s . Should I put the style => inbox inside the android array?

Comment: yeah I have same problem even with new plugin. How did you send this payload to Ionic? Can you please post how you are sending the payload to Ionic notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to make it work the way I want it, not without creating my own plugin. I ended up changing the plugin with https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push#inbox-stacking as the one I was using was outdated and unmaintained.